# C# Reading XML with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Bank>
  <Customer id="0">
    <FName>Adam</FName>
    <LName>Kruz</LName>
    <Accounts>
      <Acount id="0" money="1500" />
      <Acount id="1" money="6500" />
    </Accounts>
  </Customer>
</Bank>
```

My LINQ code:

```
private void loadCustomers()
{
    customers =
        (
            from c in XDocument.Load("database.xml").Root.Descendants("Customer")
            select
                new Customer((int) c.Attribute("id"), (string) c.Element("FName"), (string) c.Element("LName"))
                    {
                        accounts =
                            (
                                from a in c.Descendants("Account")
                                select new Account((int) a.Attribute("id"))
                                            {
                                                money = (double) a.Attribute("money")
                                            }
                            ).ToList()
                    }
        ).ToList();
}
```

Problem:

I have a generic list of class Customer. That class contains 3 properties and another generic list of class Account. I've been able to load Customer data (id, fname, lname) but I dont know how to load any data from Accounts sub tree :(

code gives me an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Xml.Linq.dll - Additional information: Value cannot be null.

I've been trying many variants of the code and I just could not make it work :( Can someone post me a working code how to load Accounts subtree ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: change your your xml `<Acount` to `<Account` or change code `c.Descendants("Acount")`

Comment: thanks I was pretty tired when I wrote this :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works for me. But you have typing error in XML - "Acount" instead "Account"...

Comment: Yeah thanks. I found this out in morning :( it seems too much programing and little bit of sleep is not good for finding errors

Answer (score 1):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
var list = xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    Id=c.Attribute("id").Value,
                    FName = c.Element("FName").Value,
                    LName = c.Element("LName").Value,
                    Accounts = c.Descendants("Acount")
                                .Select(a => new{
                                    Id= a.Attribute("id").Value,
                                    Money = a.Attribute("money").Value,
                                })
                                .ToList()

                })
                .ToList();
```

PS: Since the tag name in your xml is `Acount`, I used the same name.